# OBS studio capture webcam only?

Tags: obs

When I use webcam as an input device, obs studio puts the webcam in the upper left corner of a big black area.  How to have only the webcam exported to file?

Update: this is what I see when using OBS.  I cannot see the webcam input unless looking at the properties.  The background is black.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the corners of the webcam object on the screen and expand it to fit the canvas.  Make sure the webcam source is the correct resolution (in the Sources column, right-click on Video Capture and click Properties, then check the Preset drop down).

Also check the Base (canvas) resolution is the size you want in the Preferences - Video settings.

Animated gif showing the process:

[image: animated gif showing the process]

Comment: Hello tomh.  I am not sure what you mean by grab the webcam object on the screen and expand it to fit the canvas.  The only way I can see the webcam is by inspecting the properties.  See added image in OP.

Comment: added a gif showing the process